# Meteorjs & Handlebars: How can i put a function to a Value from the database?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a Meteor Collection where i store dates and times (my work timesheet). The times are saved as seconds.

When I show them in the template all I do is a

```
Days.find({})
```

and i can use it in my template like this:

```
<template name="calendar">
  {{#each days}}
    <p>
      {{> day}}
    </p>
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="day">
  <p>
    {{date}} - {{time}}
  </p>
</template>
```

Now as 'time' is in seconds it will display something like 30240 (time in seconds) but what I really want to show is 8h 24m. How can i add a function to that template that calculates hours and minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**converting your time to a string**

You could add in a helper to your day template, to convert it to the form you want:

```
Template.day.helpers({
    niceTime:function() {

        var timeInMs = this.time; //'this' is the current data context
        var datetime = new Date(timeInMs); //convert this to a date object
        return datetime.toLocaleTimeString; //return the time in a locale string
    }
});
```

Then in your template use `{{niceTime}}` instead of `{{time}}`

It also depends a bit on what you store your time as. If its in javascript unix time its stored in milliseconds since 1970 or the number of milliseconds from the start of the day. If it is in seconds you would need to multiply it by 1000 first. If you used `.getTime()` to get it when you store it in meteor you can use the above as is.

If you store in seconds from the start of the day add the milliseconds from 1970 (beginning of unix time) to your time.

```
var today = new Date();
var timeInMs = (this.time*1000) + new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()).toTime();
```

**Store your date as a date object**

All in all it might be better to store your date as a `Date` object. Then you can get the date out `toLocaleDateString()` or time out `toLocaleTimeString()` as you please & have it adjust to the different timezone depending on where the browser is (since at its core it will store dates & times in unixtime which is in UTC). Additionally, you wouldn't have to store the time seperately.

Comment: As I Store my time that I have worked I can't use a Date Object (or can I?) But Template.*.helpers is what I was looking for, thank you!